# Burned-out lines only in small resolution?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

If I'm rendering dark thin lines over a light background, I get kind of a burned-out result. But if I render the same in huge scale - and rescale it down to original size - the result is as expected. Its the same with texture or geometry.

[image: pic]

What can I do to prevent always rendering huge pictures in order to get a decent result?

Comment: What render engine do you use ? Blender Internal or Cycles (please add a tag)

Comment: This looks like the right job for a Vector Graphics drafting application like Inkscape or Illustrator instead. Anyway check your antialiasing settings

Comment: I created the graphic in Illustrator. Its just one part of a detailed model. I can not find any AA settings in cycles.

Comment: In Cycles, anti-aliasing is essentially how many samples you have. You should have at least 100.

Comment: It is rendered with 1024 samples. I already tried out different settings but still have no clue how to solve that.